# Admob banner ads not showing in Android 4.4 (KITKAT) but works fine in higher apis levels

Tags: java, android, admob

I am using AdMob banner ads but they are not showing in lower versions the lower version i have tested on is Android 4.4.2 Kitkat but working fine in higher Android versions. I have searched this problem but didn't find any help in other questions.Hope, i will find help here.

Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
```

XML:

```
            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Application.java:

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "App ID");
```

Fragment:

```
  AdView mAdView = v.findViewById(R.id.adView);
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
  mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

This is test ads UnitId.

Comment: Can you check if the ads are being initialised?

Comment: yes let me add the code here in post

Comment: <manifest>     <application>         <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->         <meta-data             android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"             android:value="YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID"/>     </application> </manifest> Have you added this line in manifest.xml? Also use the latest version 17.2.0 for improvements and fixes.

Comment: Yes it's added in Manifest
When i change the dependency to 17.2.0 i get the following error:
ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0.
1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this to your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```